# How do I create a multiple y axis chart in HTML where both Y values are User input?

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

[Example of what I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbUt7.png) I would prefer to do this in HTML as opposed to excel since for now I don't need to save any of this information and do not want to recreate a spreadsheet every day. For the time being this is just a proof of concept to show live data for the day.

I have a decent understanding of HTML but am by no means an expert.

I am trying to create a chart to display actual vs planned production over different time periods. I am trying to have the x-axis be the time periods. Every hour over an 8 hour period being a point on the axis. And then have two y axis values, Actual and Planned, be taken from a user input text box on the website.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  var dps = []; //dataPoints.
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{              
        title:{
            text: "Planned vs Actual Production"
        },
        axisX:{
          title: "Hour",
            valueFormatString: "####",
            interval: 1
        },
        axisY:[{
            id: "2",
            title: "Planned",
            lineColor: "#369EAD",
            titleFontColor: "#369EAD",
            labelFontColor: "#369EAD"
        }],
        axisY2:[{
            title: "Actual",
            lineColor: "#7F6084",
            titleFontColor: "#7F6084",
            labelFontColor: "#7F6084"
        }],
function addDataPointsAndRender() {
                Actual = Number(document.getElementById("Actual").value);
                Planned = Number(document.getElementById("Actual").value);
                dps.push({
                    axisY: Actual,
                    axisY2: Planned
               });
                chart.render();
            }
    data: [
    {
        type: "column",
        showInLegend: true,
        //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
        name: "Planned",
        xValueFormatString: "####",
        dataPoints: [
            { x: 1, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 2, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 3, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 4, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 5, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 6, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 7, axisY: Planned },
            { x: 8, axisY: Planned }
        ]
    },

    {
        type: "column",
        showInLegend: true,                  
        axisYType: "secondary",
        //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
        name: "Actual",
        xValueFormatString: "####",
        dataPoints: [
            { x: 1, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 2, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 3, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 4, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 5, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 6, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 7, axisY2: Actual },
            { x: 8, axisY2: Actual }
        ]
    },

    ]
    });

    chart.render();}
  var renderButton = document.getElementById("renderButton");
            renderButton.addEventListener("click", addDataPointsAndRender);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Actual:
    <input id="Actual" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Actual">
    Planned:
    <input id="Planned" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Planned">
    <button id="renderButton">Add DataPoint & Render</button>
    <button onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Reset Hour</button>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I am running into specifically is getting user input into the arrays for axisY and axisY2

Any tips or suggestions of where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you run this, do you get any errors in your console? I would think you would, as adding a function definition in the middle of an object literal like that is... unusual.

Comment: Yes. I am currently working through the console errors. So far all missing or extra expressions. Current one is "expected expression, got '}'    Line 81 Column 15.    Using firefox as my main browser.

I am brand new to canvasjs so I could very well be missing something in the formatting for it.

Comment: Sorry, Realize line 81 is probably not helpful.
});
                chart.render();
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CanvasJS accepts x and y values in dataPoints as an object ({x: xValue, y: yValue}). Passing it in this format should work fine. Please find the working code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  var dpsPlanned = [], dpsActual = []; //dataPoints.
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {              
    title:{
      text: "Planned vs Actual Production"
    },
    axisX:{
      title: "Hour",
      valueFormatString: "####",
      interval: 1
    },
    axisY:[{
      id: "2",
      title: "Planned",
      lineColor: "#369EAD",
      titleFontColor: "#369EAD",
      labelFontColor: "#369EAD"
    }],
    axisY2:[{
      title: "Actual",
      lineColor: "#7F6084",
      titleFontColor: "#7F6084",
      labelFontColor: "#7F6084"
    }],
    data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        showInLegend: true,
        //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
        name: "Planned",      
        dataPoints: dpsPlanned
      },

      {
        type: "column",
        showInLegend: true,                  
        axisYType: "secondary",
        //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
        name: "Actual",      
        dataPoints: dpsActual
      },

    ]
  });
  chart.render();

  function addDataPointsAndRender() {
    var actual = Number(document.getElementById("Actual").value);
    var planned = Number(document.getElementById("Planned").value);
    dpsActual.push({ y: actual });
    dpsPlanned.push({ y: planned });
    chart.render();
  }
  
  var renderButton = document.getElementById("renderButton");
  renderButton.addEventListener("click", addDataPointsAndRender);
 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Actual:
    <input id="Actual" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Actual">
    Planned:
    <input id="Planned" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Planned">
    <button id="renderButton">Add DataPoint & Render</button>
    <button onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Reset Hour</button>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, how would one add multiple bars, for example to compare actual vs planned hours, units produced, orders made etc? So it would compare multiple planned y values to multiple actual y values....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be your issue:

```
Actual = Number(document.getElementById("1").value);
Planned = Number(document.getElementById("2").value);
```

First thing here... Your input Ids aren't "1" and "2", they're "Actual" and "Planned" `.getElementById("Actual").value`, `.getElementById("Planned").value`

The other thing is is appears you're declaring global variables with `Actual = Number(...` instead of `var actual = Number(...` I don't know enough about your scope to say this is wrong, but something to consider.

Comment: I changed the ids as you suggested. I also changed the variables to not be global. But for the scope of this it doesn't really matter. It is a best practice though. I essentially only need a quick and dirty way to display actual vs planned production by the hour.

Still having no success getting it to display. I'm checking for syntax errors. But I really want to know if I have the format for the arrays correct, or if i am completely off on how I am trying to accomplish this.

Comment: First, sorry to say I've no experience with multidimensional arrays, (I think that's what that is), hopefully someone else comes along with more knowledge. Second, open the Developer Toolbar for your browser and find the Console. If any errors occur, you'll see them here. Also, consider using something like `console.log("myVar = "+myVar);` at certain points in your code to make sure things are working as expected. That will also display in the developer toolbar Console.

Comment: I haven't tried anything with multidimensional arrays in a few years. Since college. And I've never tried graphing or plotting them.

I'll add a console log to help see where it is breaking down. Thank you for the suggestion.